# How to add a new value to the end of an array using spread operator in ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have initialized the state as:

```
this.state = {
    buildingNames: []
}
```

Then , I am adding new values to my array inside my function as :

```
onClickAddBuildingTextBoxHandler = (inputData) => {
    this.setState({ buildingNames: [...this.state.buildingNames, inputData.value] });   
}
```

So, in my render function I am renderingthe values of the array as:

```
this.state.buildingNames.map((buildings, i) => {
    return (
        <div key={'building' + i}>
            <div className={classes.sceBuildingNameContainer}>
                <div className={classes.sceBenchmarkingBuildingName}>
                    {this.state.buildingNames} //its returning a single element
                </div>
                <button
                   className={classes.sceCloseIcon}
                   onClick={this.onClickDeleteBuildingIconHandler}>
                       <i className={"fas fa-times " + classes.sceBuildingCloseIcon} />
               </button>
            </div>
        </div>
}
```

So, what is currently happening is, the map function is not working properly. I mean the block is returning the same value twice. And when I add a new value, it gets appended to the previous state. So, if my image , if I add a new value again,, it will get appended after **mnpq** .What I want is to add the new values one after the other.How do I set the new state for that case?

[image]

Comment: Do you want to keep your old buildingNames and add the new ones to it or do you want to erase and replace them with the new ones?

Comment: @kev I want both of them, I want the new ones ones to be added to the array.Its like adding a new building.So, when I add, it will be shown below the previous one in the UI.

Comment: Then please have a look at my answer. Assuming inputData.value is one buildingNames or an array of buildingNames objects it should work.

Comment: @kev, I tried the way you mentioned in the answer, but its still giving me the same problem. Its getting appended to the end of the previous value.Its not returning a new block for the new name, it getting added to the end of the previous name.

Comment: I see, the problem is in your return() statement. A second please...

Comment: @kev, is there some issue in the map function. Is something wrong with that part?

Comment: I think it was a problem with not indexing the buildingNames array in the map function. Updated answer.

Comment: @kev It works now.Thank you so much :)

Comment: @Atomzwieback re-read the map function. It's "buildings.map((oneBuilding, i) => { ... })" The first parameter is a single value of the array.

Comment: @Noch_ein_Kamel i know saw it to late but i cant re-edit it because too less char changes -.-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first argument to the `map function` is a reference to the current element of the array map is looping on.

```
onClickAddBuildingTextBoxHandler = (inputData) => {
    const tempState = [...this.state.buildingNames];
    tempState.push(inputData.value);
    this.setState({ buildingNames: tempState });

  }



this.state.buildingNames.map((building, i) => {
    return (
        <div key={'building' + i}>
            <div className={classes.sceBuildingNameContainer}>
                <div className={classes.sceBenchmarkingBuildingName}>
                    {building} //Here you are refrencing the current element.
                </div>
                <button
                   className={classes.sceCloseIcon}
                   onClick={this.onClickDeleteBuildingIconHandler}>
                       <i className={"fas fa-times " + classes.sceBuildingCloseIcon} />
               </button>
            </div>
        </div>
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but "this.state.buildingNames is an array so you should index it in your map function like this: this.state.buildingName[i]" is not correct. Inside the map function you should use "buildings" to access the current building. Variable name is not right ;-)

Comment: Du hast recht @Noch_ein_Kamel. Ich habe meine antwort berichtigt.

Answer (score 2):

You're using `map` to iterate over the elements in the `buildings` array. The first argument in the callback function is the current element, so change that from the plural `buildings` to `building`, and then reference that in your JSX `{building}`. In addition there's no need to prefix "building" to the key id.

```
this.state.buildingNames.map((building, i) => {
  return (
    <div key={i}>
      <div className={classes.sceBuildingNameContainer}>
        <div className={classes.sceBenchmarkingBuildingName}>
          {building}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );   
}
```